# Iterating over keys (or k/v pairs) in zsh associative array?

Tags: zsh

In zsh, I want to iterate over an associative array.  I need both keys and values.  But when I iterate over the associative array normally (`for x in $assoc_array`), I get only values.

All examples I've looked at show that, *given a key*, you can get its value from an associative array.  My problem is getting the set of keys to begin with.

Does zsh support iterating over keys in an associative array?

Comment: If you have just a small list this might be an option: `for i in a,b c_s,d ; do KEY=${i%,*}; VAL=${i#*,}; echo $KEY" XX "$VAL; done`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can get both keys and values at once with this nifty parameter expansion:

```
for key val in "${(@kv)assoc_array}"; do
    echo "$key -> $val"
done
```

See [Parameter Expansion Flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) in the Zsh manual.

Comment: This is way simpler +1

Comment: This doesn't work when the keys or values have spaces in them

Comment: `(@kv)` is better (it works with quotes, too.).

Comment: @HappyFace edited

Comment: You should add double-quotes around the expansion so that empty values don't trip it up (e.g. an array set with `declare -A assoc_array=([a]=A [b]= [c]=C)` will print incorrectly)

Comment: @Gairfowl edited

Answer (score 41):

I continued searching after asking my question and found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111397/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts) on the Unix StackExchange:

```
typeset -A assoc_array
assoc_array=(k1 v1 k2 v2 k3 v3)

for k in "${(@k)assoc_array}"; do
  echo "$k -> $assoc_array[$k]"
done
```

Output is:

```
k1 -> v1
k2 -> v2
k3 -> v3
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to test this in a useful way, try with the builtin `$options`. (See `man zshoptions`)

Comment: What if the key is not an increasing number like foo, bar, etc like arr[foo]=baz?

Comment: @Timo I don’t think you should expect any specific order in associative arrays.