# ZSH list variable name in for loop causes error, but works in BASH

Tags: zsh

New ZSH user here writing his .zshrc file, which uses GNU find and a for loop to source shell scripts in ~/.aliases that set up my shell aliases. 
I just spent over an hour on the internet and trying various things wondering why this code worked in BASH, but not in ZSH:

```
$ for aliases in $(find ~/.aliases -maxdepth 1 -name "*_aliases"); source $aliases

aliases: attempt to set slice of associative array
```

Over an hour later, I happened to re-write that code with a different variable name:

```
$ for files in $(find ~/.aliases -maxdepth 1 -name "*_aliases"); source $files
```

and it worked.

How is ZSH treating this code differently than BASH and why? Are there any advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives us the clue what happens:

> aliases: attempt to set slice of associative array

The parameter `aliases` is used by *zsh* to store the alias which are defined. It's defined as an associative array and you cannot store a scalar into it.

Use e.g. [this code](https://superuser.com/a/737353/195224) to display the content of associative arrays nicely formatted:

```
for k in "${(@k)aliases}"; do
  echo "$k -> $aliases[$k]"
done
```